# Keep radio button selected after a form submit

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I am using below code to keep the radio button selection after a form submission, but it keep resetting to the last button after form submission

```
<input type="radio" name="button" value="Yes" <?php if(isset($_POST['button']) == 'Yes')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> />Yes
<input type="radio" name="button" value="No" <?php if(isset($_POST['button']) == 'No')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> />No
```

How can I keep the selection ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns a [`boolean`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). As such, comparing directly to `Yes`/`No` is not what you want.

What you want is:

```
if (isset($_POST['button']) && $_POST['button'] == 'Yes')
```