# Keep selected value after post check

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a enquete. 1 of the pages looks like this:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="true" id="x" name="x">
    <table>
        <b>How relevant where the topics for your current and/or future business?</b>
        <hr />
        <tr>    
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="question1">
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1">1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="2">2</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="3">3</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="4">4</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="5">5</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="6">6</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="7">7</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="8">8</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="9">9</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="10">10</td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment1"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <br /><br />
    <table>
        <b>How did you value the networking opportunity?</b>
        <hr />
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="question2">
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="1">1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="2">2</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="3">3</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="4">4</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="5">5</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="6">6</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="7">7</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="8">8</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="9">9</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="10">10</td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment2"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input id="enquete_next" type="submit" name="Add" value="Next">
<?php 
//If the form gets submitted, check if everything is okay.
if(isset($_POST['x'])){
$validcomment = false;
        //validate if the answers are not empty. if they are empty go the the else statement.
        if(!empty($_POST['answer1'])){
            if(!empty($_POST['answer2'])){
                $validcomment = true;
            }else{
                echo "Please fill in all the questions!" . "<br>";
            }
        }else{
                echo "Please fill in all the questions!" . "<br>";
        }
        //If the form is filled in, and checked. Then do this!
        if($validcomment){
            insert_page1();
        }
}
?>
</form>
```

The following code is working. So when i fill in answer 1, but leave answer 2 empty. i get a message: Please fill in all the questions.

However, i would like the form to keep its values. so i only have to fill in the empty answer instead of the whole form.

Because right now, when it checks. The form gets empty and i have to fill it in all over again.

Comment: Search on google for form validation in Core PHP

Comment: validate the form first before submitting

Comment: Save in sessionStorage or php session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="hiden_field" value="<?php $_POST['hiden_field'] ?>" id="x" name="x">
    <table>
        <b>How relevant where the topics for your current and/or future business?</b>
        <hr />
        <tr>    
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="question1">
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1" <?php if($_POST['answer1']==1){ echo "checked"; } ?>>1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="2" <?php if($_POST['answer1']==2){ echo "checked"; } ?>>2</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="3" <?php if($_POST['answer1']==3){ echo "checked"; } ?>>3</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="4" <?php if($_POST['answer1']==4){ echo "checked"; } ?>>4</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="5" <?php if($_POST['answer1']==5){ echo "checked"; } ?>>5</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="6" <?php if($_POST['answer1']==6){ echo "checked"; } ?>>6</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="7" <?php if($_POST['answer1']==7){ echo "checked"; } ?>>7</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="8" <?php if($_POST['answer1']==8){ echo "checked"; } ?>>8</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="9" <?php if($_POST['answer1']==9){ echo "checked"; } ?>>9</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="10" <?php if($_POST['answer1']==10){ echo "checked"; } ?>>10</td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment1"><?php if($_POST['comment1']){ echo $_POST['comment1']; } ?></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <br /><br />
    <table>
        <b>How did you value the networking opportunity?</b>
        <hr />
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="question2">
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="1" <?php if($_POST['answer2']==1){ echo "checked"; } ?>>1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="2" <?php if($_POST['answer2']==2){ echo "checked"; } ?>>2</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="3" <?php if($_POST['answer2']==3){ echo "checked"; } ?>>3</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="4" <?php if($_POST['answer2']==4){ echo "checked"; } ?>>4</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="5" <?php if($_POST['answer2']==5){ echo "checked"; } ?>>5</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="6" <?php if($_POST['answer2']==6){ echo "checked"; } ?>>6</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="7" <?php if($_POST['answer2']==7){ echo "checked"; } ?>>7</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="8" <?php if($_POST['answer2']==8){ echo "checked"; } ?>>8</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="9" <?php if($_POST['answer2']==9){ echo "checked"; } ?>>9</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="10" <?php if($_POST['answer2']==10){ echo "checked"; } ?>>10</td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment2"><?php if($_POST['comment2']){ echo $_POST['comment2']; } ?></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input id="enquete_next" type="submit" name="Add" value="Next">
<?php 
//If the form gets submitted, check if everything is okay.
if(isset($_POST['x'])){
$validcomment = false;
        //validate if the answers are not empty. if they are empty go the the else statement.
        if(!empty($_POST['answer1'])){
            if(!empty($_POST['answer2'])){
                $validcomment = true;
            }else{
                echo "Please fill in all the questions!" . "<br>";
            }
        }else{
                echo "Please fill in all the questions!" . "<br>";
        }
        //If the form is filled in, and checked. Then do this!
        if($validcomment){
            insert_page1();
        }
}
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in sessions.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['data'];
```

And then in the form you can show it like this:

```
session_start();
<input type="text" name="data" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['data'];?>"/>
```

More about session variables: [Session variables - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

And also, as @Swaraj Giri mentioned. You should **always** sanitize user input data. Here's a question on StackOverflow that has a well explained answer on how to approach that: [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: Please add a note about sanitizing user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="true" id="x" name="x">
    <b>How relevant where the topics for your current and/or future business?</b>
        <hr />
    <table>

        <tr>    
            <td><input type="hidden" value="1" name="question1"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1">1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="2">2</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="3">3</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="4">4</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="5">5</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="6">6</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="7">7</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="8">8</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="9">9</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="10">10</td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment1"><?php echo $_POST['comment1'];?></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <br /><br />
        <b>How did you value the networking opportunity?</b>
        <hr />
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="2" name="question2"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="1">1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="2">2</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="3">3</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="4">4</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="5">5</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="6">6</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="7">7</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="8">8</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="9">9</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="10">10</td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment2"><?php echo $_POST['comment2'];?></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input id="enquete_next" type="submit" name="Add" value="Next">
<?php 
//If the form gets submitted, check if everything is okay.
if(isset($_POST['x'])){
$validcomment = false;
        //validate if the answers are not empty. if they are empty go the the else statement.
        if(!empty($_POST['answer1'])){
            if(!empty($_POST['answer2'])){
                $validcomment = true;
            }else{
                echo "Please fill in all the questions!" . "<br>";
            }
        }else{
                echo "Please fill in all the questions!" . "<br>";
        }
        //If the form is filled in, and checked. Then do this!
        if($validcomment){
            insert_page1();
        }
}
?>
</form>
```

I could fix the text area but not the radio button!!!

[Keep radio button selected after a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450998/keep-radio-button-selected-after-a-form-submit)

for radio button!!